# Is there a way to find the height of UIWebView content synchronously/in place (without waiting for delegate callback)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm using a `UIWebView` in a cell, and the cell asks for its height. Currently I need to load the webview, wait for its `finishedLoading` callback, then check its height there. This means that the height requesting function has to return with some preliminary value before the `UIWebView` loads shortly thereafter.

However, I'm not loading a complex webpage, I'm loading an HTML string with some special HTML that I'm configuring with CSS that I can't replicate with `NSAttributedString`.

The loading of this string is almost instant due to the small size, so I'd love if I could wait until it returns before returning an incorrect height, then correcting it and the user seeing a jump.

Is there a way to do this? Load the webview and get its height in place without waiting for callbacks that take no time at all anyway?